# HTML & Javascript Form doesn't submit on smaller screens

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML form which is submitted via JavaScript function. It works as expected when submitting on full-screen windows, however, when submitting in a smaller window, such as a smartphone or simply a minimized window on a computer, it doesn't do anything other than quitting the form.

I tried checking by adding a console log when clicking, but nothing is logged when browsing from a smaller display. Below is the code that make up the form.

**HTML**

```
<form id="volunteer-form">
  <div class="firstNameTF">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="First Name" name="First Name" placeholder="Your first name"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="lastNameTF">
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="Last Name" name="Last Name" placeholder="Your last name"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="facultyTF">
    <label>Faculty</label>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="Faculty" name="Faculty" placeholder="Your faculty"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="YearDropdown">
    <label>Year</label>
    <div>
      <select id="Year" name="Year">
        <option value="1">First</option>
        <option value="2">Second</option>
        <option value="3">Third</option>
        <option value="4">Fourth</option>
        <option value="Postgraduate">Postgraduate</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="AffiliationTF">
    <label>Affiliation</label>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="Campus Affiliation" name="Campus Affiliation" placeholder="Your student affiliation/involvement"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="EmailTF">
    <label>E-mail Address</label>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="Email Address" name="Email Address" placeholder="Your e-mail address"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <button type="submit"id="submit-form">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// Check if text fields are complete
$('#submit-form').on('click', function (e) {
  console.log("clicked subimt");
  e.preventDefault();
  var empt = document.forms["volunteer-form"]["First Name"].value;
  var empt1 = document.forms["volunteer-form"]["Last Name"].value;
  var empt2 = document.forms["volunteer-form"]["Faculty"].value;
  var empt3 = document.forms["volunteer-form"]["Campus Affiliation"].value;
  var empt4 = document.forms["volunteer-form"]["Email Address"].value;
  var c = 0;
  var close = document.getElementsByClassName("closebtn");
  var i;

  if (empt == "" || empt1 == "" || empt2 == "" || empt3 == "" || empt4 == "") {
    console.log('form failure')
    // window.alert('All fields are required')
    // Show error alert
    console.log("pop errorAlert");
    if (c == 0) {
      document.getElementById("errorAlert").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("errorAlert").style.opacity = "1";
      c = 1;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("errorAlert").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("errorAlert").style.opacity = "0";
    }
  } else {
    var $form = $('form#volunteer-form'),
      url = 'FORM_URL'
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
      url: url,
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      data: $form.serialize()
    }).done(

      console.log("success"),
      document.getElementById("volunteer-form").reset(),
      // window.alert("Thank you for joining me in this campaign! We'll be in touch soon!")

      // Show success alert
      function pop() {
        if (c == 0) {
          document.getElementById("successAlert").style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById("successAlert").style.opacity = "1";
          c = 1;
        } else {
          document.getElementById("successAlert").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("successAlert").style.opacity = "0";
        }
      })
  }

  // Loop through all close buttons
  for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    // When someone clicks on a close button
    close[i].onclick = function () {

      // Get the parent of <span class="closebtn"> (<div class="alert">)
      var div = this.parentElement;

      // Set the opacity of div to 0 (transparent)
      // div.style.opacity = "0";
      // div.style.display = "none";

      $(div).css({
        "opacity": "0",
        "display": "none"
      })

      // Hide the div after 600ms (the same amount of milliseconds it takes to fade out)
      setTimeout(function () {
        div.style.display = "none";
      }, 600);
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Check from the browser inspector 'Network' option what response you are getting when you click on the submit button. This may give a clue.

Comment: Other than it looks like you're missing an element in your form called "errorAlert" which is causing your JS to fail ... do you have any CSS for this form for styling?

Comment: @devd Thank you I checked the network option and it logs as if the button worked although no request is made to the server..

Comment: @KummerWolfe Thank you. The "errorAlert" element is not missing, it's just in a different part of the code.